# Sphere contour edge color in surf plots

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm using the function `surf` to draw a sphere:

```
[x1,y1,z1]=sphere(16);
surf(...,'EdgeColor','k')
```

However, the `EdgeColor` draws a line for each vertex of each face of the sphere. Is it possible to only draw the contour edge of the sphere and not each face vertex (i.e. the circle contour)?

Comment: This question is still unanswered.

Comment: Do you need the contour edge to show up from every viewing angle, or just from a single fixed viewpoint?

Comment: Since the sphere are in 3D, yes they have to be the same no matter the viewing angle. Something similare to [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FRJQw.png).

Comment: Okay, that is fairly different from the previous example of what you want that you showed me. I've been playing around trying to figure out work-arounds to get you what you want. To get lighting effects, you can specify a `camlight` value. `camlight headlight` will set the camera light to be directly toward the current camera position, which provides a stronger contrast between the sphere and the background (though still not a distinct boundary like you want). My second work-around to follow in next comment...

Comment: If you want something that looks like the image you just sent me, then you can simply plot your point using `plot3(centre_x, centre_y, centre_z, 'ok', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r')`. If you need bigger or smaller markers, you can specify the marker size, and if you need different colours, just change the MarkerFaceColor. If you want lots of spheres, just put `hold on` and loop through to plot each one in whatever specific colour you want.

Comment: Since both sample images you sent are quite different, though, I don't know if either of these will work for you. If neither of these options work, can you try being more specific as to the exact requirements you need to be able to plot?

Comment: @Mozglubov The first sample was in the case I was generating spheres in Matlab, with this case I wanted to remove the face edges and just have the output edge of the sphere. Now if I use the `plot3` function and that I'm not generating spheres, it might works and reproduces what I want. Thanks for your help. You could propose this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get coloured circles with a black border, you can use the plot3 function to produce black circles filled with a specified colour:

`plot3(centre_x, centre_y, centre_z, 'ok', 'MarkerFaceColor', [R G B])`

This should allow you to loop through each circle you want to plot and specify an individual internal colour.